# FacebookGraphAPIError: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_photos) on node type (User)

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using passport.js for Facebook authentication and I started to get this error recently. Full error message looks like this:

```
FacebookGraphAPIError: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_photos) on node type 
(User) at D:\app\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:167:21 at passBackControl 
(D:\app\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:124:9) 
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\app\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7) 
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20) at _stream_readable.js:908:16 at 
process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I tried different approaches to set permissions scope. Initially I declared it in

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    profileFields     : ['user_photos', 'user_friends'],
}
```

Then I moved it to

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', 
{ scope : ['email, public_profile, user_photos, user_friends'] }));
```

And it still causes the same error, as well as user_friends if I remove user_photos. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Core of my authentication script was inspired by this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook

Comment: likely to be impacted by fb api change..

Comment: Did you have any luck on this? I can't get 'user_friends' to come through. No problem with 'email' or 'public_profile'.

Answer (score 4):

"Some Facebook integrations require approval before public usage."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Your app, either in production or in testing, needs to be reviewed.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit

Until reviewed and approved by Facebook, your app can use only the public profile of an user and his/her email.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from public profile and email, the other permissions require that you submit your app for approval.
So what you do is :

1. go to the app dashboard.
2. Go to 'Roles' and select 'Test Users'.
3. Create a  test user(allows you to create more than 1) and grant them all the permissions you plan to request.
4. In the 'App Review' section make sure the app is set to development mode\
5. Select the permissions you wish to seek approval for.

Now when performing the screencasts for those permissions, make use of the test user....with permissions already granted by that user, you can perform your screencast without any hitches.

After your app is approved, you can switch your app mode to live.